# Definition of ImageChops.difference

Tags: python, image-processing

I am using the ImageChops library in order to use the difference function to compare two images:

```
im1 = Image.open("image1.jpg")
im2 = Image.open("image2.jpg")
diff= ImageChops.difference(im1, im2)
```

How exactly does the difference function work? What is it actually doing inside?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ImageChops.difference computes the 'absolute value of the pixel-by-pixel difference between the two images', which results in a difference image that is returned. The code for it is at https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/src/PIL/ImageChops.py#L88. More precisely, for 2 images, image1 and image2 it returns the following as a new image:

```
image1.im.chop_difference(image2.im)
```

where:

1. chop_difference is defined as (PyCFunction)_chop_difference at https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/43c5f2cd649bdc8422dd2892b1e3349ea003fb46/_imaging.c#L3085
2. _chop_difference is mapped to ImagingChopDifference at https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/43c5f2cd649bdc8422dd2892b1e3349ea003fb46/_imaging.c#L2016
3. ImagingChopDifference is an external function referenced at https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/4aba749c3c0ff0bc24b525886c0c89c3dca1d43f/libImaging/Imaging.h#L322 and defined in Chops.c at http://svn.effbot.org/public/tags/pil-1.1.4/libImaging/Chops.c as:

   ```
   ImagingChopDifference(Imaging imIn1, Imaging imIn2)
   {
       CHOP(abs((int) in1[x] - (int) in2[x]), NULL);
   }
   ```
4. CHOP is the following function-like C macro , which is also defined in Chops.c. It clips the result of arithmetic operations to be in range(256). Note that in this code the '#' does not begin a comment, rather '#define' is a C directive for defining a constant or creating a macro.

   ```
   #define CHOP(operation, mode)\
       int x, y;\
       Imaging imOut;\
       imOut = create(imIn1, imIn2, mode);\
       if (!imOut)\
           return NULL;\
       for (y = 0; y < imOut->ysize; y++) {\
           UINT8* out = (UINT8*) imOut->image[y];\
           UINT8* in1 = (UINT8*) imIn1->image[y];\
           UINT8* in2 = (UINT8*) imIn2->image[y];\
           for (x = 0; x < imOut->linesize; x++) {\
               int temp = operation;\
               if (temp <= 0)\
                   out[x] = 0;\
               else if (temp >= 255)\
                   out[x] = 255;\
               else\
                   out[x] = temp;\
           }\
       }\
       return imOut;
   ```
5. After preprocessing the code in (4) and (3) using cpp, the GNU C preprocessor, the result is the compilable ImagingChopDifference function as follows:

   ```
   static Imaging
   ImagingChopDifference(Imaging imIn1, Imaging imIn2)
   {
       int x, y;
       Imaging imOut; 
       imOut = create(imIn1, imIn2, NULL);
       if (!imOut) 
           return NULL; 
       for (y = 0; y < imOut->ysize; y++) {
           UINT8* out = (UINT8*) imOut->image[y]; 
           UINT8* in1 = (UINT8*) imIn1->image[y]; 
           UINT8* in2 = (UINT8*) imIn2->image[y]; 
           for (x = 0; x < imOut->linesize; x++) {
               int temp = abs((int) in1[x] - (int) in2[x]); 
               if (temp <= 0) 
                   out[x] = 0; 
               else if (temp >= 255) 
                   out[x] = 255; 
               else out[x] = temp; 
           }
       } 
       return imOut;
   }
   ```

The GNU C Preprocessor, cpp, is widely used on Linux and Unix systems. The CentOS 7.0 man page for it is at http://www.unix.com/man-page/centos/1/cpp/. Its complete manual is at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/index.html, which includes a chapter on macros.

CHOP is an acronym for CHannel OPeration, where channel refers to a digital image channel (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Channel_%28digital_image) and clipping the result of channel operations is documented in http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagechops.htm).

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping , but is there a way to see whats inside Chop.c ?

Comment: @Prince: absolutely, just click on the link I provided for it, http://svn.effbot.org/public/tags/pil-1.1.4/libImaging/Chops.c, and take a look. The clipping makes sense since all values in an image array should be in range(256). This can be seen by loading images into an numpy array with arr = misc.imread('image_pathname') after running 'from scipy import misc' and then arr.max() gives its max value and arr.min() gives its min value. In some image formats with RGB representation a pixel consists of 3 elements in the image array, at least that's how Java's ImageIO class does it.

Comment: @Prince: I updated section 5 to include C code for the compilable ImagingChopDifference function after Chops.c has been preprocessed with cpp.